# Form POST not doing anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a webapplication made in ASP.NET Core (latest version) which needs to use a pop-up form where 1 value has to be filled in and then send it back to the controller to later use that value.

So the process is like this: Button > Click on button > Pop-up form pops up (Image: [pop-up form which is a partial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1XE2.png)) > Fill in value > Submit > Send result back to controller.

But whenever I press the submit button it sends me to a 400 error not found page. What could go wrong?

Here is the partial view pop-up form code:

```
@model IEnumerable<ApplicationName.Models.Moederblad>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <a class="b-close">x</a>
    //Actionresult > Controller
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Incassodatum", "Moederblads", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="Incassodatum">Incassodatum</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Bijvoorbeeld: 19-02-2020" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Dat is geen geldige datum" data-val-regex-pattern="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)[0-9]{2}$, " id="Incassodatum" name="Incassodatum">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" value="Toevoegen" id="submit">
    }
</div>
```

Here is the corresponding controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Incassodatum()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Automatisch de datum van vandaag in het Incassodatum veld zetten nadat er op een knop is gedrukt
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Incassodatum(string Incassodatum)
        {
            string date= "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                date = Incassodatum;
            }
            else
            {
                date = "Something went wrong.";
            }
            TempData["Incassodatum"] = $"{Incassodatum}";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Then later I can use the tempdata to read out the value but its not working at all so that is actually useless for now.

I tried adding the [Route("Moederblads/Incassodatum")] property above the post.
I tried it in a normal view (So not a partial view) and there I could see the value with F12.
Tried changing object names as I thought it might conflict with other names.

Don't know what to do now. Any of you have a guess?

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work because the model used in the pop-up view is of type IEnumerable, but the taghelper 'asp-for' needs a single model type. @JaredWare

Comment: Try it: public ActionResult Incassodatum([Bind(your fields)]string Incassodatum), your fields like Insodatum, Moederblads and so on. Your fields among quotes

Comment: Did not work @pnet

Answer (score 0):

> But whenever I press the submit button it sends me to a 400 error not found page.

A 400 error is a Bad Request. A 404 is a Not Found. As such, I'm not sure which you're actually getting here. However, based on the fact that you have an input with `__RequestVerificationToken` as the name, and you're using it wrong at that, I'm leaning towards the 400.

Since you're trying to use this input as a button, you've set a value on it to apply that text to the button. However, that's going to actually post that value for `__RequestVerificationToken`, and it's *not* a valid token. As such, you're going to always get a 400 Bad Request because of the failed request verification.

The request verification token should be on a hidden input, so the simplest solution is to remove the name from that button and add a hidden input specifically for the request verification token: `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

Even better would be to use the built-in `FormTagHelper` instead, which automatically takes care handling antiforgery tokens:

```
<form asp-action="Incassodatum" asp-controller"Moederblads" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Finally, while it doesn't technically effect anything, using `input` for buttons is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. Use `<button type="submit">` instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Will try! It was the 404 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Was something very easy in the end: I just had to delete the: [HttpPost] tag above the method and the [HttpGet] method as it did nothing in the end. After that it hit my break point and could verify that the value is coming through fine :)